# Who / What am I if I am a talking ring?

Tags: riddle

**Here's the riddle:**

---

Call on me, I answer you.

I am a ring but I'm not for you.

I can talk, I think it's surprising too!

You see me away from apples

Stuck on windows

My games are right up my sleeve

But sometimes every now and then, your anger will want me to leave

---

I have a sister

She is older than me

She doesn't have time to give opinions about me,

But I think we're both trying to make the world better.

---

My voice is soothing

I'm a perfect lullaby singer

But not only that

but I can sing nursery songs, too!

I have tons of them, right in here!

July is my boss's dreams

**Hint:**

> Open up the **gate**s!

Comment: Ring from `lord of the ring` !! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it

> Cortana (Windows assistant similar to siri)

Call on me, I answer you.

> You can say "Hey Cortana" and it answers you.

I am a ring but I'm not for you.

> That's Cortana's logo.

I can talk, I think it's surprising too!

> Sort of (not really) new tech some people may be suprised by their phone talking to them

You see me away from apples

> Not found on apple

Stuck on windows

> Only on windows

My games are right up my sleeve

> Cortana has "Guess the Horror movie" game and such games if you ask her to start one.

But sometimes every now and then, your anger will want me to leave

> Those voice assistants often drive me nuts

I have a sister
She is older than me

> Probably sister siri who has been around longer

She doesn't have time to give opinions about me,

> Siri says "No comment" when you ask her about Cortana.

But I think we're both trying to make the world better.

> When you ask Cortana if she likes Siri, she says "Of course, we're both trying to make the world a better place.

My voice is soothing
I'm a perfect lullaby singer
But not only that
but I can sing nursery songs, too!
I have tons of them, right in here!

> You can ask Cortana to sing

July is my boss's dreams:

> July is Windows' (In this case, Bill Gates') special release month.

The hint:

> As you know, Bill **Gates** made Windows, the OS that has Cortana, so "Open up the **gate**s" is a key.

Comment: Correct! But fix that blockquote

Comment: But the answers to my hints are kind of incorrect, should I edit it them to the correct answer?

Comment: And there's more information I'd like to add, can I?

Comment: @AbAppletic be my guest.

Comment: As for the blockquotes I added spoiler tags and then didn't actually type an answer for that line which is why they show up skinnier and don't reveal an answer.

Comment: I suggested an edit.

Answer (score 2):

Possible answer:

> Siri

Call on me, I answer you.

> If you talk to siri she talks back

I can talk, I think it's surprising too!

> Siri can talk to you

You see me away from apples

> Other companies have versions of siri

Stuck on windows

> 

But sometimes every now and then, your anger will want me to leave

> 

Comment: You got extremely close, but not it

Comment: If you read the question one more time, I think you'll get it :D

Comment: Hmm I'm starting to think my edit isn't correct either haha

Comment: You got close again, but still wrong. And your last 2 blockquotes are broken

Comment: I feel sorry for you, you got too close :P